# Where is SQL Server Data Tools 2012, after installing SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I've installed `SQL Server 2012` (in July 2015) on my computer, next to SQL Server 2010. When I try to open SQL Server Data Tools 2012 (see also a printscreen [here](http://prntscr.com/8bpcxf)), the previous version of Visual Studio (`SSDT 2010`) is opened. I'd like to open and use the 2012 version.

Where is SQL Server Data Tools 2012?

I assume the 'old' .exe is opened `("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe")`. Can anybody tell me what the location or .exe name is of SQL Server Data Tools 2012 and where it should be located? Is it different than the location I stated above? If I haven't installed it at the right place, I can probably find it on my computer with search.

I'll do an new installation if there's no other option. So, anyone can tell me the .exe-name and/or the file-location, or other suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 RTMed in March 2012. VS 2012 RTMed in August of that year. So, the SQL Server Data Tools 2012 were built for VS 2010. There is no SQL Server 2010.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I'm not sure how to interpret your comment: You know or assume I have VS 2010 installed? Is it so that with SQL Server 2012 one always has SSDT as VS 2010? If not: how do I know for sure? I installed a few months ago.

Comment: *What* did you install? SSDT is a separate download. Installing SQL Server 2012 doesn't install the latest SSDT. Check the list of the latest SSDTs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis . That possibly solves it. I recall I did one full install with both of them but it looks like my memory fails me.     I'll take a look tomorrow at the site.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and @PanagiotisKanavos: it appears the reason VS 2010 was opened is because I had not installed VS 2012. I wrongly assumed that with the installation of SQL Server 2012 automatically also Visual Studio 2012 was installed. So, I did the install of VS 2012. And then changed the SSDT link to `11` instead of `(...) (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ (...)`, and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `I wrongly assumed` that with the installation of SQL Server Management Studio 2012, automatically also Visual Studio 2012 was installed.

The accompanying install of VS 2012 is `not` the case. I (possibly faultly) remember that in a previous download I downloaded both Management Studio AND Visual Stuadio, in one download.

So the answer to my question (Where is SQL Server Data Tools 2012?) is: NOT on your computer.

If you enounter the same issue, then first found out whether SSDT 2012 has been installed.

Some info beneath to figure that out and to do it: 
The icons of 2010 and 2012 differ, see [here](http://prntscr.com/8c1kai) (sorry, I haven't got enough rights to post an image directly).

In my case first Visual Studio 2012 had to be installed. I did that from this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015. 
And then I changed the SSDT link into `11` instead of `(...) (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ (...)`, and now it works. Also see a new printscreen of the new SSDT link [here](http://prntscr.com/8c1l2a).